# Processing Interactive Grid manually through PL/SQL and keeps throwing out an error

Tags: database, plsql, oracle-apex

Used this site https://community.oracle.com/thread/3937159?start=0&tstart=0 to learn how to manually process interactive grids. I got it to work on a small table with 3 columns, but when I tried to get it to work for a bigger table, it keeps throwing this error:

> PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small for.

I tried only updating 1 column and converting the datatype to the correct one, and it is not going away.

Comment: Show code please. It helps us help you and then helps others.

Answer (score 1):

this message usually means you're trying to store 'AAAA' into a column that only accepts 1, 2 or 3 chars, like `varchar2(3)`.

Make sure your columns have a proper limit size for the data you're processing.

Comment: I tried only updating one column and converting the bind variable to the exact data type of the database and it doesn't work. This error shows up even if I am deleting which makes no sense.

Comment: Hmm... Is there any trigger in place doing something funny?

Comment: How can I find whether the trigger exists or not

Comment: I found that there are triggers in place. I will try to figure out what they do and get back to you :)

Comment: I disabled the triggere and the problem didn't go away so its unrelated.

Comment: Can you replicate your problem on apex.oracle.com so we could see it better?